# java jdbc mysql -resultset getMetaData returned a strange value

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This is my sql query string:

```
select t.create_date, concat('+', t.points) as points,
                case t.obtain_ways
                     when 'PURCHASE_PRODUCT' then '理财赠送'
                     when 'SOCIAL_NETWORK_SHARE' then '社交网络分享'
                     when 'CHECK_IN' then '签到'
                     when 'RAFFLE' then '抽奖'
                end  as obtain_ways
                from points_record t where [custId] and delete_flag=0
```

when I use mysql function such as concat or sum function and my sql string contains chinese characters, tthe value of getColumnType from ResultSetMetaData is strange.

```
ResultSetMetaData resultmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
int type  = resultmd.getColumnType(2);
// type is -3 VARBINARY
```

The type is -3 which is VARBINARY,but it should be 12(VARCHAR).

When I use english words instead of chinese characters every thing is OK.

```
select t.create_date, concat('+', t.points) as points,
                case t.obtain_ways
                     when 'PURCHASE_PRODUCT' then 'a'
                     when 'SOCIAL_NETWORK_SHARE' then 'b'
                     when 'CHECK_IN' then 'c'
                     when 'RAFFLE' then 'd'
                end  as obtain_ways
                from points_record t where [custId] and delete_flag=0
```

The column type：

```
ResultSetMetaData resultmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
int type  = resultmd.getColumnType(2);
// type is 12 VARCHAR
```

But when I use another database which is installed another computor,whatever I use chinese character or english words ,the result is OK.

My project encoding is UTF-8, my db encoding is:

```
Variabile_name                     value
character_set_client                  utf8
character_set_connection              utf8
character_set_database              utf8
character_set_filesystem              binary
character_set_results                utf8
character_set_server                  utf8
character_set_system                  utf8
character_sets_dir                  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\share\charsets\
```

and another db encoding is:

```
Variabile_name                     value

character_set_client                  utf8
character_set_connection              utf8
character_set_database              utf8
character_set_filesystem              binary
character_set_results                utf8
character_set_server                  utf8
character_set_system                  utf8
character_sets_dir                  /usr/local/mysql/share/charsets/
```

Comment: It sounds like a bug, are you using the latest MySQL Connector/J driver? If not: upgrade and try again, otherwise file a bug report.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thank you very much.I updated the mysql-connector-java  version to 5.1.38 and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yesterday, I updated my mySql database, finally everything is OK.The version of my old mySql is 5.1 and my latest mySql is 5.7.May be that's a bug of mySql.